# tikzmark: How to add a '['-bracket / square brace on content?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

**€dit - New Text:**

I have some content (pgfplotstable and some text)  and would like to add a *square brace on the left side*, *like this is a "bmatrix"*.

What is the best way to do that? 
What have I to do? Using tikzmark or tikzmarknode or...?

**€dit - NEW MWE**, but not nice implemented at all...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}
\noindent\tikzmarknode[]{OL}{} \\
Hello World. \\
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
} \\[0.1em]
Goodbye World. \\[-3mm]
\tikzmarknode[]{UL}{}


\tikz[overlay,remember picture, red, transform canvas={xshift=-3pt}]{
\draw  (OL.center) -- +(1ex,0);
\draw (UL.center) -- +(1ex,0);
\draw[line cap=rect, blue] (OL.center) -- (UL.center);
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `\tikzmark` and not `\tikzmarknode`. However, I am not sure since I do not understand "Because of pgfplotstable-content and so on, it should be tikzmark, not the normal way in the math-mode." What does that mean? BTW, what is the purpose of `transform canvas={xshift=-3pt}` (instead of just `xshift=-3pt`)? Also the gaps between the red and blue line can be avoided with `line cap=rect`.

Comment: Try with `line cap=rect` on the blue line.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\noindent\tikzmarknode{OL}{\rule{5cm}{4cm}} 
\tikz[overlay,remember picture, red]{\draw ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north west)--++(1ex,0) ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south west)--++(1ex,0)
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north east)--++(-1ex,0)([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south east) -- ++(-1ex,0);
\draw[blue,line cap=rect] 
([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north west)--([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south west)
([xshift=3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north east)--([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south east);}
\end{document}`

Comment: New MWE!  ................................................

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newsavebox\cistable

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\cistable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
} 
\end{lrbox}%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=OL]
 \path node(tab){\usebox{\cistable}}
 (tab.north) node[above] {Hello World.} 
  (tab.south) node[below] {Goodbye World.};
\end{scope} 
\draw[red] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north west) -- ++(1ex,0)
 ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south west) -- ++(1ex,0)
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north east) -- ++(-1ex,0)
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south east) -- ++(-1ex,0);
\draw[blue,line cap=rect] 
([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south west)
([xshift=3pt,yshift=3pt]OL.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]OL.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mmmh, with content --> savebox --> tikz-node I understand and would know how to do. And there is no way with tikzmark?

Comment: @cis There certainly is but the savebox it is IMHO the easiest way to control all distances precisely.

Comment: @cis With `\savebox` you also only need a single run for all things to fall into the right place.

Comment: @cis In addition to what Henri is saying with this method you have full control over whether or not the braces are drawn in `overlay` mode. It makes IMHO more sense to not use `overlay` here because you may not want them to run over other stuff or the page border.

Comment: With savebox there should be a method for `$\left[ \mysavebox \right.$`. The colors has been for illustraion, not an aim.

Comment: @cis Frankly, how would one know what the aim is? There might be very good reasons for using `tikzmark` (which I really really like) but IMHO your MWE does not provide those who write an answer with such reasons.